# Problem with typescript while making request to SWR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, swr

I want to know what is the type of this args that is being passed to my function below

```
const fetcher = async (...args) => {                                
~_  0   const res = await fetch(...args);                                                                       
    1                                            
~   2   return res.json();                                                                                      
    3 };
```

This is my fetcher function for SWR, and this is the error I'm getting

```
[tsserver 2556] [E] Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0 or more.
```

SWR hook

```
const { error, data } = useSWR(`/api/albums/list/${user.id}`, fetcher)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is TypeScript signature of `fetch` function:

```
declare function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

If you use functions [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) `...args`, your `fetcher` function can be called with zero parameters like this and tsc will not report errors.

```
fetcher();
```

Or, many parameters(like four parameters):

```
fetcher("localhost", {}, {}, {});
```

Then, you use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to call the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). The parameter of spread does not satisfy the function signature of fetch(the parameter can NOT be zero or more than two), so tsc reports an error.

So you'd better modify it like this:

```
const fetcher = async (
  input: RequestInfo,
  init: RequestInit,
  ...args: any[]
) => {
  const res = await fetch(input, init);
  return res.json();
};
```

package version: `"typescript": "^4.1.3"`

Comment: Since you're not doing anything with additional arguments beyond the first two, wouldn't it be better just to leave off the `...args` entirely?

Comment: @SimonW Yes, I’m not sure if the `fetcher` needs other parameters. So I keep `...args`

Comment: Hi, do you have an example of how it would be used?
I am left wondering, how should I make the call to the fetcher passing it the init object with its values.

Example:
`const {data, error} = useSWR("/some/path", fetcher("some/path", {headers: {}}))`

What would be the correct way?